# Unexpected server response Server Environment Check Error in TYPO3 ver12.4.1

Tags: server, typo3, response, environment

I tried to check if the Server Environment passes the internal TYPO3 test after fresh installation of the New v.12.4.1 of the TYPO3 CMS system. SO, in the Backend Admin Panel I go to the "Environmment"--> "Check Environment" and I get the following error:

Unexpected server response
http://mywebsitedomain.org/typo3/install/server-response-check/host?src-time=1685741154&src-hash=5581b8a933668bdf5fac5ac905dd5d62ac7f913c: HTTP Location header contained unexpected "a1df49e630.random.example.org"

What does it mean and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This may indicate, that your webserver is configured wrong. If TYPO3 is served by Apache from the default host, Apache sets the SERVER_NAME variable directly to any (untrusted) host-header value. If you have access to the Apache configuration, please set `UseCanonicalName On` directive.

If you do not have access to Apache configuration, you must adapt `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['trustedHostsPattern']` to a value matching your website domain(s). For more details see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Security/GuidelinesIntegrators/GlobalTypo3Options.html#trustedhostspattern